# How can I create a shell script through a python code?

Tags: python, shell

I have written a python code inside which at a certain line I want to write a file xyz.sh but its saying permission denied. I tried to use os.rename() also but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you upload your source code?

Comment: Do you have write permissions in the folder? Also, could you provide some code snippets?

Comment: This is not a valid question, give us your code, the place where you want to create file, show us permissions on this directory, etc, etc, etc ..

Comment: This could do with an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know your code, we can't give an exact answer. But here are some hints:

If you are new to linux, you may want to check that if you want to use a relative path, you are not allowed to start the path with a `/` at the beginning.

Further we don't know which part fails (execution or writing). If execution fails check that:

Before execution your file has to be marked as executable. In the command line you could do: `chmod +x xyz.sh`

If you want to execute a relative path you have to start the path with a `./` at the beginning. (i.e. `./scriptsInMyProgramFolder/xyz.sh` )

Please be a bit more precise next time. ;-)